# With crafting writs, what determines the required materials?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

At first, I thought they were set to the type of area you were in, but I noticed in Auridon that the crafting writs switched from maple to oak as required material for woodworking.

Is the material type reliant on the character level or the skill level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, the material type and reward level is determined by your Solvent Proficiency, Metalworking, Tailoring, Aspect Improvement, Recipe Quality, or Woodworking passive, depending on the writ.

For blacksmithing, woodworking, alchemy, and clothing skills, it is wise to tie it to character level manually, as material collection is easier when monsters are dropping solvents and deconstructables that you require.

Comment: Thx! Checked it out just now. Worth noting that turning in the writs is at a level specific area though.

Comment: @Vahx The turn-in spot is determined by where you pulled the writ in the first place.

Comment: My experience says different, at first i thought the level of the writs were linked to the area that you pull them from. But i pulled a maple level woodworking in Grathwood and it required me to go to Auridon to turn it in. (at least the quest marker did). I'll double check next time i do a writ but i'm 99% sure of this (in my head)

Comment: Just to confirm, i picked up a writ in Auridon today and had to turn it in at the Grathwood drop off, with my crafting levels at 2.